# meteor compilation - error output doesn't show where is the error?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to run my meteor app, and get the following runtime error :

```
    While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
   native: Unexpected token }
   at Object.parse (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp._inferFromPackageJson (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:165:1)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.inferExtraBabelOptions (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:139:1)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:81:1)
   at BabelCompiler.<anonymous> (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:21:1)
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:20:1)
```

I don't see which file is having an issue. Is there any option to have more information about the error ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not being super helpful, but it is telling you in line 2

```
   native: Unexpected token }
```

Which means you have an unbalanced brace - If you are using a modern editor like Atom or Sublime (or others), then it should be able to highlight that for you.

I know it doesn't tell you which file, but look at the file you edited most recently, or even use

```
git difftool
```

to show you what has changed since your last commit

Comment: I am on brackets, I am unsure : emacs should be only linked with html files ? Meteor is 100% javascript :-/

Comment: It doesn't matter which editor you use as long as it has the features to help you, ie syntax highlighting, bracket/brace matching etc. Ideally you use one editor for all files, ie html, js, css etc I don't use emacs but I'm sure it has bracket matching features :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7259

I found There was an issue on my package.json file.

I don't really know which one : maybe a comma that shouldn't really be somewhere...

Comment: Good that you found it. Probably something to remember: if it's not reporting an error with a source file, it's something earlier in the build chain (like parsing the package.json file)